# Generate a 4D array with different sized arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I'm having a .skeleton images which are 3D images. one .skeleton file contains a variable number of frames. Each frame has 50 joints and all 50 joints are contained with their x,y,z cordinates.

for an exampe, consider a .skeleton file with 150 frames, where each frame containts 50 joints and each joint contains x,y,z cordinate. So I created put the values into a 4D array, [1,150,50,3].

The other file contains 148 frames , 50 joints and each joint with x,y,z cordinate. [1,140,50,3]
Hence for each .skeleton file the number of frames varies, but the other are fixed. 
ex: [1,200,50,3]

The total number of .skeleton files are 2500. So I need to combine the into a single ndarray. For an example,
[2500,XXX,50,3]

But I'm unable to do this since the number of frames in the .skeleton files are different. Can someone tell me how I can achieve this? How can I decide the common number of frames. For an example to convert it to [2500,300,50,3]. Kindly help.

This is what I have done so far

```
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import csv

skeleton_files_mask = os.path.join(SKELETON_DIR, '*.skeleton')
skeleton_files = glob.glob(skeleton_files_mask) #glob is a general term used to define techniques to match specified pattern according to rules related Unix shell
#skeleton_files is a list of path names of the file

print ('Number of .skeleton files ',len(skeleton_files))

max_frame_count = 300
max_joints = 50

full_ds = []
total = []

#for idx, file_name in enumerate(skeleton_files[:568]):
for idx, file_name in enumerate(skeleton_files): 
    if idx%100 == 0:
        print(idx)
    basename = os.path.basename(file_name)
    #os.path.basename(path) : It is used to return the basename of the file . This function basically return the file name from the path given
    print (basename)
    name = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]
    label = name.split('A')[1]
    with open(file_name) as f:
        framecount = int(f.readline())

        print ('Frame count.....',framecount)
        #Frame count..... 158
        #Frame count..... 102
        sequence_frames = []

        for frame in range(framecount): # Looping across 158
            body_count = int(f.readline()) #1/2
            #print ('body_count.....',body_count)
            if body_count <= 0 or body_count>2:
                print('continue, no body')
                break
            joints_xyz = []
            for body in range(body_count): #1/2
                skeleton_info = f.readline()
                joint_counts = int(f.readline()) 
                #print ('joint_counts.....',joint_counts)
                for joint in range(joint_counts): #25/50
                    joint_info = f.readline() #loop goes for 25 times
                    #print ('joint_info.....',joint_info)
                    joint_info_array = joint_info.split()
                    #print (joint_info_array)
                    x, y, z = joint_info_array[:3]
                    #print (x,y,z)
                    joint_info_xyz = np.array([float(x), float(y), float(z)])
                    #print('joint_info_xyz', joint_info_xyz.shape)
                    joints_xyz.append(joint_info_xyz)
            pad_joints = max_joints - len(joints_xyz)
            joints_xyz = np.array(joints_xyz)
            joints_xyz = np.pad(joints_xyz, ((0, pad_joints), (0, 0)), mode='constant')
            frame_xyz = np.stack(joints_xyz)
            #print('frame_xyz', frame_xyz.shape)
            sequence_frames.append(frame_xyz)
            #print (sequence_frames)
            #X = np.array(sequence_frames)
        total.append(sequence_frames)
            #print (total)
        if len(sequence_frames) > 0:
            file_name = os.path.join(NPY_DIR, name+ '.npy')
            sample = [name+'.npy', int(label)-1]
            full_ds.append(sample)
            #print(full_ds)
            #print (X.shape)
            np.save(file_name, np.array(sequence_frames))
print ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
R=np.array(total)

print (R.shape)
#train_ds = full_ds[:380]
#test_ds = full_ds[380:]

train_ds = full_ds[:40320]
test_ds = full_ds[40320:]

with open(os.path.join(NPY_DIR, TRAIN_DS), 'w') as train_ds_file:
    writer = csv.writer(train_ds_file, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(train_ds)

with open(os.path.join(NPY_DIR, TEST_DS), 'w') as test_ds_file:
    writer = csv.writer(test_ds_file, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(test_ds)
```

I could successfully run this for one .skeleton file. Its output was ,

```
Number of .skeleton files  1
0
S001C001P001R001A002.skeleton
Frame count..... 158
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
(1, 158, 50, 3)
```

Comment: You could read them all as individual arrays, [pad them](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to the maximum length and [mask them](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html), appropriately, then [stack them](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.stack.html) into one big masked array. But that would take the extra memory of the padding and the masks, so you may be better off with just the list of arrays.

Comment: Or you remember what frames belonged to what image and create a `[x, 50, 3]` array